# Cannot start Spring Tool Suite server

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I've just downloaded STS and create MVC project. I run it as dynamic web and get this error. How to fix?

Environment: Ubuntu 12.10, SpringToolSuite 3.5.0.

```
Publishing the configuration...
Error copying file to /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/backup/catalina.policy: /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/catalina.policy (No such file or directory)
/home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/catalina.policy (No such file or directory)
Error copying file to /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/backup/catalina.properties: /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/catalina.properties (No such file or directory)
/home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/catalina.properties (No such file or directory)
Error copying file to /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/backup/context.xml: /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/context.xml (No such file or directory)
/home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/context.xml (No such file or directory)
Error copying file to /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/backup/jmxremote.access: /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/jmxremote.access (No such file or directory)
/home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/jmxremote.access (No such file or directory)
Error copying file to /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/backup/jmxremote.password: /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/jmxremote.password (No such file or directory)
/home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/jmxremote.password (No such file or directory)
Error copying file to /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/backup/server.xml: /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/server.xml (No such file or directory)
/home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/server.xml (No such file or directory)
Error copying file to /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/backup/tomcat-users.xml: /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/tomcat-users.xml (No such file or directory)
/home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/tomcat-users.xml (No such file or directory)
Error copying file to /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/backup/web.xml: /home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/web.xml (No such file or directory)
/home/hieugioi/Programs/SpringToolSuite/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.5.SR1/base-instance/conf/web.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Have you checked that the named files exist with exactly that path? Maybe they have a different path?

Answer (score 1):

So I've been having the same problem and couldn't figure it out. I gave up. Your post got me to searching again and found [a blog](http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2011/07/error-starting-tc-server-in-sts-27.html) saying to run STS as admin (Right click on shortcut -> "Run as Administrator"). I did that, and now the server is starting fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your application server is not configured properly.
Check this:
[Configure Weblogic server](http://zakkiahmed.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/step-by-step-install-and-configure-weblogic-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a permission problem. Go to STS location and run the following command in the terminal -
$ sudo ./STS

It might solve your problem.